# Changing CurrentAccessToken in Facebook Unity SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to post to a Facebook page AS the page using the Unity Facebook SDK running on iOS. As I understand, to do that, I need the pages access token with `manage_pages` and `publish_pages`. I know that I can get it from `/me/accounts?fields=access_token`, but how do I tell `AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken` to use my pages access token instead?

Right now I'm using the following:

```
var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
//wwwForm.AddField ("access_token", "A-T I NEED");
wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "InteractiveConsole.png");
wwwForm.AddField("message", "herp derp.  I did a thing!  Did I do this right?");
FB.API("/PAGE-ID/photos", HttpMethod.POST, HandleResult, wwwForm);
```

I tried putting the access token  manually, but that didn't work (so I commented it out).

With this as it is I'm getting an error, telling me that I need `publish_actions`, which is not correct since I'm not trying to post as the user. If I also get `publish_actions` the Post goes online, but is posted to the page as the user speaking. (User is also Admin)

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I filed a bug report to facebook and as it turns out: "… at this time this functionality is not supported." Wich simply means there is now way to use the Page Access Token you acquired via the `FB.API` within the `FB.API`. And they are not going to tell you abot it in the documentation.

As a workaround I simply use a `UnityWebRequest` like this:

```
IEnumerator UploadToPage(byte[] screenshot) {

    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddField("message", "herp derp.  I did a thing!  Did I do this right?");
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "Test.png");

    string url = "https" + "://graph.facebook.com/"+ PageID + "/photos";
    url += "?access_token=" + PageAccessToken;

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, wwwForm))

    {
        yield return www.Send();

        if (www.isError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }

    Debug.Log(url);
}
```